# Que debo de usar para una variable INT en una base SQLite en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
            u.setNombre(user.getText().toString());
            u.setApellido(user.getText().toString());
            u.setBoleta(user.)
            u.setPassword(user.getText().toString());
```

Hola, buenas tardes
Me surgió este problema al hacer una base de datos para Android con SQLite, no se como hacer que el parámetro "Boleta" pase con su valor que tiene, en este caso es un INT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente, lo único que tienes que hacer es parsear el valor:

```
u.setBoleta(Integer.parseInt(user.getText().ToString());
```